# mvc razor dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to know how to put drop down list like this:

```
  <div>  
    <label>Price Range</label> 
    <select>
       <option value="1">min</option>
       <option value="50000">50,000</option>
       <option value="100000">100,000</option>
       <option value="150000">150,000</option>
   </select>
```

in the view , and read the selected parameter in the controller
tnx

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to make it work.
Its depend on your needs.

I am going to show you the simplest way to create it in the view itself

You can do it like this all inlined in your *.cshtml file like so:

```
@{ 
    var loadListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    loadListItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "text1", Value = "value1", Selected = true });
    loadListItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "text2", Value = "value2" });    
}

//Begin Form
    @Html.DropDownList("ListKey",loadListItems);
//End Form
```

Will produce the result as follows:

```
<select name="ListKey">
<option value="value1">text1</option>
<option value="value2">text2</option>
</select>
```

And on submitting it on controller side you can get the values as follows:

```
 ActionResult YourActionName(FormCollection collection){
     var selectedValue = collection["ListKey"];
 }
```